# Extract single column from multiple CSVs and save to new CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to read out a specific column from over 100 CSV files to create a new CSV file.  The source column's header will be renamed with the filename the column is extracted from.

I can get the individual columns, but I have been unable to rename each column's header without the ".csv" extension:

[image: output]

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = "C:/Users/Doc/Data"
files = os.scandir(folder)

E2080 = []
with os.scandir(folder) as files:
    for file in files:
        #print(file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None)
        dist = {file: (df['lnt_dist'])}
        E = pd.DataFrame(dist)
        E2080.append(E)

dist = pd.concat(E2080, ignore_index=False, axis=1)
dist.head()
dist.to_csv('E2080', index=False)
```

Comment: you should use `file.name` instead of `file`. And you have normal string so you can ie. `.split(".")` and get first element (name without extension). And if you want more functions then you should use `pathlib.Path()` instead of `os.scandir()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the final code that worked for me (see output [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzqsE.png)):

```
E2080 = []
with os.scandir(folder) as files:
    for file in files:
        #print(file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None)
        dist = {file: (df['lnt_dist'])}
        E = pd.DataFrame(dist)
        E_1 = E.rename(columns={file: file.name.split('.')[0]}) # rename df header while dropping the ext **[.csv]** and the `os.scandir` attribute `<DirEntry>`
        E2080.append(E_1)

dist = pd.concat(E_28, ignore_index=False, axis=1)
#dist.head()
dist.to_csv('E2080.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `file.name` instead of `file` to get `string` with name.

And with `string` you can use `.split(".")` to get name without extension.

```
for file in os.scandir(folder):
    print(file.name, '=>', file.name.split(".")[0])
```

Or you could use `pathlib.Path` instead of `os.scandir()` to have more functions.

```
for file in pathlib.Path('test').iterdir():
    print(file.name, '=>', file.stem)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @furas. `file.name` for `os.scandir` did the job after renaming the dataframe before concatenating the `items` in the list. The final code is shown in the answer section.